# Empty results using ODP.NET with Oracle stored procedure

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, odp.net

I’m developing app that uses ODP.NET to call Oracle stored procedure.
When I run procedure in sqldeveloper it works fine.
When I try to call procedure using ODP.NET it returns empty results.
I tried to change data types, values, but without success.

**Procedure call example:**

```
BEGIN "DB"."DB_API"."GETEXTENDEDCOLLECTEDDATA"(1, 50537, NULL, NULL, '20141230 00:00:00', '20150201 00:00:00', NULL, :P_CV_COLLECTEDDATA); END;
```

**Code, generated in sqldeveloper:**

```
PROCEDURE GetExtendedCollectedData
     ( p_UserId IN SEC_VS_USER_T.USR_ID%TYPE,
       p_SiteId IN SEC_NN_SERVER_T.SRV_ID%TYPE,
       p_DeviceName IN DAT_DEVICE_INFO_T.DEVICE_NAME%TYPE,
       p_PrptyName IN APP_PROPERTY_INFO_T.PRPTY_NAME%TYPE,
       p_FromDate IN VARCHAR2,
       p_ToDate IN VARCHAR2,
       p_PrptyCategory IN APP_PROPERTY_INFO_T.PRPTY_CTGRY_CODE%TYPE,
       p_cv_CollectedData IN OUT cvt_ExtCollectedData);

DECLARE
  P_USERID NUMBER;
  P_SITEID NUMBER;
  P_DEVICENAME VARCHAR2(255);
  P_PRPTYNAME VARCHAR2(255);
  P_FROMDATE VARCHAR2(200);
  P_TODATE VARCHAR2(200);
  P_PRPTYCATEGORY NUMBER;
  P_CV_COLLECTEDDATA DB.DB_API.cvt_ExtCollectedData;
BEGIN
  P_USERID := 1;
  P_SITEID := 50537;
  P_DEVICENAME := NULL;
  P_PRPTYNAME := NULL;
  P_FROMDATE := '20140101 12:00:00';
  P_TODATE := '20151212 11:59:59';
  P_PRPTYCATEGORY := NULL;
  P_CV_COLLECTEDDATA := NULL;

  DB_API.GETEXTENDEDCOLLECTEDDATA(
    P_USERID => P_USERID,
    P_SITEID => P_SITEID,
    P_DEVICENAME => P_DEVICENAME,
    P_PRPTYNAME => P_PRPTYNAME,
    P_FROMDATE => P_FROMDATE,
    P_TODATE => P_TODATE,
    P_PRPTYCATEGORY => P_PRPTYCATEGORY,
    P_CV_COLLECTEDDATA => P_CV_COLLECTEDDATA
  );
  /* Legacy output: 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('P_CV_COLLECTEDDATA = ' || P_CV_COLLECTEDDATA);
*/ 
  :P_CV_COLLECTEDDATA := P_CV_COLLECTEDDATA; --<-- Cursor
--rollback; 
END;
```

**C# code:**

```
public const string DateFormat = "yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss";
using (var connection = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (var command = new OracleCommand
    {
        Connection = connection,
        CommandText = "\"DB\".\"DB_API\".\"GETEXTENDEDCOLLECTEDDATA\"",
        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    })
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("p_UserId", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = userId;
        command.Parameters.Add("p_SiteId", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = siteId;
        command.Parameters.Add("p_DeviceName", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = deviceName;
        command.Parameters.Add("p_PrptyName", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = prptyName;
        command.Parameters.Add("p_FromDate", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = fromDate.ToString(DateFormat);
        command.Parameters.Add("p_ToDate", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = toDate.ToString(DateFormat);
        var propertyCategoryParam = new OracleParameter("p_PrptyCategory", OracleDbType.Int32)
        {
            IsNullable = true,
        };
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyCategory))
        {
            propertyCategoryParam.Value = null;
        }
        else
        {
            propertyCategoryParam.Value = Int32.Parse(propertyCategory);
        }
        command.Parameters.Add(propertyCategoryParam);
        var refCursorParam = new OracleParameter("p_cv_CollectedData", OracleDbType.RefCursor)
        {
            Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput,
        };
        command.Parameters.Add(refCursorParam);

        for (int i = 0; i < command.Parameters.Count; i++)
        {
            var p = command.Parameters[i];
            Log.Info("CSTR: " + p.ParameterName + ": " + p.Value + " - " + p.OracleDbType, this);
        }

        int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Log.Info("command.ExecuteNonQuery: " + result, this);

        var reader = ((OracleRefCursor) command.Parameters["p_cv_CollectedData"].Value).GetDataReader();

        Log.Info("command.Parameters[p_cv_CollectedData].Value: " + command.Parameters["p_cv_CollectedData"].Value, this);
        Log.Info("reader: " + reader, this);
        Log.Info("reader.FetchSize: " + reader.FetchSize, this);
        Log.Info("reader.FieldCount: " + reader.FieldCount, this);
        Log.Info("reader.Depth: " + reader.Depth, this);
        Log.Info("reader.HasRows: " + reader.HasRows, this);
        Log.Info("reader.RowSize: " + reader.RowSize, this);
```

**Log Results:**

```
4276 17:04:15 INFO CSTR: p_UserId: 1 - Int32 
4276 17:04:15 INFO CSTR: p_SiteId: 50537 - Int32 
4276 17:04:15 INFO CSTR: p_DeviceName: NULL - Varchar2 
4276 17:04:15 INFO CSTR: p_PrptyName: NULL - Varchar2 
4276 17:04:15 INFO CSTR: p_FromDate: 20140101 12:00:00 - Varchar2 
4276 17:04:15 INFO CSTR: p_ToDate: 20151212 11:59:59 - Varchar2 
4276 17:04:15 INFO CSTR: p_PrptyCategory: - Int32 
4276 17:04:15 INFO CSTR: p_cv_CollectedData: - RefCursor 
4276 17:04:15 INFO command.ExecuteNonQuery: -1 
4276 17:04:15 INFO command.Parameters[p_cv_CollectedData].Value: Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleRefCursor 
4276 17:04:15 INFO reader: Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader 
4276 17:04:15 INFO reader.FetchSize: 131072 
4276 17:04:15 INFO reader.FieldCount: 19 
4276 17:04:15 INFO reader.Depth: 0 
4276 17:04:15 INFO reader.HasRows: False 
4276 17:04:15 INFO reader.RowSize: 6476
```

Comment: Are those User Defined Types being passed in?

If so, have a look at this example, or write a wrapper SP to convert the types.

https://apexapps.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=44785:24:11490655002996:::24:P24_CONTENT_ID,P24_PROD_SECTION_GRP_ID,P24_PREV_PAGE:10199,,24